# Royal Enfield classic 350 engine off while running

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-consumption, carburetor, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

I bought a brand new Royal Enfield Classic 350 and I rode around 1200 km. Since the delivery of bike, I have faced a recurring problem with the engine shutting down while the bike is running.

When I drive the bike for around 50 km at a speed of 60-80kph, the problem occurs. After two or three minutes, the engine can start normally and later the problem repeats. While the bike is shutting off, the engine acts like it's going out of fuel. I checked with the company service center, the fuel valve got cleaned, the fuel line got cleaned, but still the problem persists. Can anyone give some suggestion for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the engine on my Royal Enfield Classic 350 shutting down?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27593/why-is-the-engine-on-my-royal-enfield-classic-350-shutting-down)

Comment: Clogged gas cap vent? Try riding with the cap not fully closed and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

There was a minor dust particle which lies inside carburator, after cleaning it got resolved

Comment: Crazy how those carbs can mess up anything :).  Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: But carbs are the best thing @Cullub

Answer (score 0):

I have this recurring problem as well..it’s due to the poor design of the bs4 tank and it causes air lock inside the tank ..open the tank and close it and then start the engine in fuel ON mode ..hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem in Gixxer, the problem was solved after the fuel injector plunger was changed. Generally the mechanics understand when you say to change the pin in the fuel injector.

Comment: Weird.  I was mechanic for awhile and have never heard of a fuel injector pin.  Do you have a picture?  Can you explain it?  Do you have a diagram you can share ?

Comment: The OP probably means "pintle," the mechanical part of the injector that moves and permits or prohibits fuel from passing through into the combustion chamber or intake manifold.